# Finding matrix representation of an operator given an eigenproblem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, hilbert-space, linear-algebra

I have to find the matriz representation of $L_z$ to finish a problem and I was given these two informations: $$L_z|+>=\hbar|+> \ L_z|->=-\hbar|->  $$
and
$$|+> = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ i\end{bmatrix}
\
|-> = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ -i\end{bmatrix}$$

So I decided to open $L_z$ as a matrix to find it's values, like

$$L_z=\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    c & d 
  \end{bmatrix}$$
Following, I multiplied $L_z$ with |+> in matricial form:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    c & d
  \end{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    i 
  \end{bmatrix} 
=\frac{\hbar}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    i 
  \end{bmatrix} 
$$ 
And the same for the second eigenproblem
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b \\
    c & d
  \end{bmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    -i 
  \end{bmatrix} 
=\frac{-\hbar}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    -i 
  \end{bmatrix} 
$$

After, I could isolate $a,b,c,d$ and found that 
$$L_z=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & -i\hbar \\
    i\hbar & 0
  \end{bmatrix} 
$$

Is this correct? Or do I have to use another method?

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because check-my-work questions are off-topic.

Comment: My bad, it'll never happen again, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perfect! Just note that the representation becomes diagonal in the {(1, 0) ,(0,1) } basis. What you did is correct. Play around in different basis to get a feel for what is happening. Good luck!